# Using both Thymeleaf and JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I was using JSP + JSTL but I'm boring of c:if, c:choose, ...

So, I want my JSP pages to be rendered with both JSP and Thymeleaf (I plan to remove all JSTL as soon as possible). I am using the **Spring MVC** framework:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

In my controller, I just return the jsp without extenion.

```
return "folder/page";
```

<strike>Can my JSP pages be renderd first with the JSP resolver and then with the Thymeleaf resolver? If yes, how?</strike>

It seems that it is very complicated to chain JSP and Thymeleaf. So, I want to use the Internal resolver for JSP files and Thymeleaf template resolver for HTML files. How can I do it?

Comment: Some thoughts on your idea: you may provide your own ViewResolver which instruments `ServletContextTemplateResolver` and `InternalResourceViewResolver`, but it would process both simultaneously which might lead to a heavy WTF-scenario. Just as a comment because I don't see any solution to get both processed in a chain.

Comment: I understand so how can I use JSP for *.jsp files and Thymeleaf for *.html files? Do I have to change stuffs in my controller?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you now 'just' want to make the switch based on the returned view? So no hybrid view handling. You may try it by changing the filename suffix for the Thymeleaf ViewResolver to html. It may fall through the InternalViewResolver without any exception and trigger the templateResolver. So you just rename your new templates to *.html. I have no code and libs here to test this idea.

Comment: If it is impossible aor a real pain, I need to find another solution. So I want now to add Thymeleaf for HTML template files. I'll keep JSP support because I need time to rewrite them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer based on @Igd response

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.jsp" />
</bean>
<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewNames" value="redirect*" />
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.html" />
</bean>
```

And i use this for the mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/view1")
public String thymeleafView(){
    return "mythymeleafview.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/view2")
public String jspView(){
    return "myjspview.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 21):

According to [this post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Chaining-view-resolvers-td3295026.html) on the Thymeleaf forum, you have two solutions.

**First solution** :

*Remove the suffix property* in your bean declaration (`<property name="suffix" value=".html" />` and `<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />`) and *pass the suffix* in the return value of your controllers, e.g. :

```
@RequestMapping("/view1")
public String thymeleafView(){
    return "mythymeleafview.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/view2")
public String jspView(){
    return "myjspview.html";
}
```

**Second solution** :

Add the `viewNames` property to the resolvers. The value is the name of a folder which contains views depending on their extension. So you will have one folder for JSP files and another for HTML (thymeleaf) files, e.g. :

*Configuration*

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
     <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
     <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

*Controller*

```
@RequestMapping("/view1") 
public String thymeleafView() { 
     return "thymeleaf/mythymeleafview"; 
} 

@RequestMapping("/view2") 
public String jspView() { 
     return "jsp/myjspview"; 
}
```

*Project folder*

```
WEB-INF/views/jsp/myjspview.jsp
WEB-INF/views/thymeleaf/mythymeleafview.jsp
```

Both solutions work but have some contraints. You have to specify one way or another whether you want to resolve with JSP or Thymeleaf.

The "perfect" solution to chain JSP and Thymeleaf — which would consist in trying to resolve the view with JSP when it cannot be resolved with Thymeleaf or *vice versa* — is not possible, and Daniel Fernández (Thymeleaf team) explained why in [this same post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Chaining-view-resolvers-td3295026.html) :

> Thymeleaf allows you to create whichever ITemplateResolver implementation you wish, including some that might not allow to determine whether the template exists or not before actually reading it. [...] So, there is no way for Thymeleaf to be sure whether a template will be resolvable or not before trying to process the template. And that's why the ThymeleafViewResolver has to resort to the "viewNames" property.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, two servlets works fine. The key is to keep servlet configuration minimal and include an appConfig.xml for database and other services (this avoids massive duplication of configuration)

**Web.xml:**

```html
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>AssessmentAdmin</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>AssessmentAdmin</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/xz/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   
   
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>AssessmentAdminTL</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>   
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>AssessmentAdminTL</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/xztl/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ........
```

**servlet for jsp:**

```html
<mvc:annotation-driven />
 
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
   <!--  <property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />-->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>



 ..........



 
 <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />



</beans>
```

**servlet for thymeleaf**

```html
<mvc:annotation-driven />
 
<!-- Thymeleaf -->

<bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
  </bean>
    
  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>
   
  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean> 
    
 
   
  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>  
  
  


 
 <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```

Tried it and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

according to @Athanor's answer,we may have another choice.

we use property "viewNames" to control which resolver the template select

```
<!-- jsp -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*admin/*,*packer/*,*courier/*,/" />
</bean>
<!-- thymeleaf -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*thymeleaf/*" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

and the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public ModelAndView dboxPrint(Model model){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("thymeleaf/dbox_print");

    return modelAndView;
}
```