# Using Thymeleaf and jsp together in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have been developing an application currently using jsp pages. For a certain need , i need to have thymeleaf working also. Is this possible to do? and if so , what would be the best way to ensure the .html files are sent to the thymeleaf resolver and jsp's continue to be sent to their current resolver. . i currrently have this in my conf

```
<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480223/using-both-thymeleaf-and-jsp) ?

Comment: @heRoy . i see your answer and it seems very helpful. however , when i try do your solution 2 , i get an error on this line  <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" /> . it says No setter found for property 'viewNames' in class 'org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver' . any idea how to fix it ?