# spring boot set jstl default to open jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I'm opening jsp pages through jstl spring boot

I included JSTL and Jasper in my pom.xlml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and i added the configuration to my web application

```
 @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

this is the request mapping in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/linkExpired", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String linkExpired(HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "LinkExpired";
    }
```

and my jsp files are in webapp/WEB-INF/views

Everything works fine until i added thymeleaf dependency to my pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

i started getting this exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template

I tried to add this configuration but I am still getting the same error:

```
@Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
```

anyone knows how to force JSTL to open jsp pages rather than thymeleaf?

Comment: Why are you using Spring Boot and first thing is very hard try to not use it? What yu have configured and added is already provided by Spring Boot (which according to the tags you use). Then use the starters and create the appropriate templates (or jsp pages).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `ServletContextTemplateResolver`. So create it:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
     <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
     <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
```

And for that you want to keep JSP, you will have your jspResolver and templateResolver together and just in controller you are able to create request mapping for jsp and another one for template.
Here is already answered question if you want to see how to create controllers:
[Using both Thymeleaf and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480223/using-both-thymeleaf-and-jsp)