# Why Spring Boot forces me use Thymeleaf templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have tried go to login page in my Spring boot app and I got this error

```
Circular view path [/login.jsp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login.jsp] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

On stackoverflow people give advice that need add thymeleaf dependency

`('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')`

but after that I got this error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

this error indicates that Spring can't find template login.html in `/resurses/templates` folder.
What I should do if I have my own login.jsp in another folder and I don't want use any templates?

This is my login mapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {

        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }
```

and this is my Security config

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
 }
```

Comment: How did you define path reference to your .html files??

Comment: @Afridi I have no any .html file in my project I have ony .jsp files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just create your own mapping for your login page in your controller like:

```
@Controller
public class AppController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            view.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            view.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }

        view.setViewName("your-login-page");  
        return view;
    }
}
```

And configuration should look like so:

```
    @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().and()
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
        }
```

And application.properties files should look like so:

```
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.your-file-type
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp-pages/
```

where "/WEB-INF/jsp-pages/" is your files directory

Comment: I have added login mapping and configuration to my post. I do not see any fundamental difference between your and my config/mapping. I tried change controller method like your (using ModelAndView instead String) and I still get same error (((

Comment: How did you define path reference to your .html files??

Comment: I have no any .html file in my project I have ony .jsp files

Comment: But I have another problem after that, Thymeleaf engine don't parse jsp format `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup`

Comment: @DmitryOleinik By default Thymeleaf only supports html files. But check this post, may be it help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480223/using-both-thymeleaf-and-jsp

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Boot does not force you to use, it encourages you.

You can use `.jsp` pages if you want, to do this you need to:

1 - Add this in your `MainClass.java`

```
@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainClass.class);
    }
```

2 - Add this in your `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

3 - Put your `.jsp` pages in the mapped folder and you can use `.jsp` instead of `thymeleaf`.

Comment: It's my first configuration. Unfortunately it don't work. In this case I have `Circular view path [/login.jsp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login.jsp] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`