# My project can't find jsp file, I think the problem is in application.properties file, but dont know how to fix it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

My project can't find jsp file. I try to add in application.properties these rows, but this didn't work

```
spring.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

When i my controller return html page everything is ok, but this doesnt work with jsp
This is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=AdminToolWeb
spring.datasource.username=mssqllogin
spring.datasource.password=mssqllogin$
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Тhese are my files in the project. I try to call Movie.jsp
[image]

The error is

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Movies], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zetcode</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootSubmitFormEx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It looks like your mixing JSP and Thymeleaf templates. I don't think this will work with property based configuration only. Maybe look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693728/use-jsp-and-thymeleaf-views-in-spring-boot-app

Comment: jsp only work in war files and inside a WEB-INF folder not the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still seem to use Thymeleaf as template engine. To use JSP templates you need to add `tomcat-embed-japser` as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Additionally I think the templates need to be in a `src/main/webapp` folder of your project and not the resources folder.

And as @CostiCiudatu mentioned the properties must be `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` (with the `spring.mvc` prefix).

You can do this configuration programmatically as well by adding a custom view resolver bean in any of you `@Configuration` classes:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
  final InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
  viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  return viewResolver;
}
```

---

*UPDATE:*

After taking a look at the repository it turned out that you still had the Thymeleaf dependency in the pom.xml and thus on the classpath which caused the problems with JSP templates.

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/svetliosa/CinemaWeb/pull/1/commits/8b8f0c7a48c08eb0587de753364a9bb8a991055e) that addresses this issue and configures your project as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60213442/4323935 as you apparently want to use both JSP and Thymeleaf templates.

However - unless there is a very good reason to use multiple template engines - I'd recommend to stick with one template engine only. Thymeleaf is a reasonable default for Spring Boot and there should be a good reason to diverge from this default! Using multiple template engines is a non standard use-case and might cause problems in the future (e.g. with Spring updates, etc.)

Comment: @SvetoslavPanteleev I updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: I don't have such a class, but I created it. Where exactly and how should I use it. Do i have to use it in the Application.java. I will add images for my new config file and application.java file
https://prnt.sc/10oyn1q - new config file
https://prnt.sc/10oyojx - application.java

Comment: You can add it directly in the `Application` class

Comment: Аnd again donw show me the file, do you want to send you github link to the project to help me, because for the fifth day I can't fix it, but I have to keep working on it because it's my diploma project. I will be very grateful if you can help me

Comment: @SvetoslavPanteleev Yes, please share the project link

Comment: https://github.com/svetliosa/CinemaWeb
- There are two applications in one, the code is not very clear, but I will refactor it when everything is ready. First you can access from http://localhost:8080/ The seccond http://localhost:8080/indexCinema After Login can't find Movie.jsp. You can skip the logic and return the page directly or I can send you and database

Comment: can you give me some contact like email / discord so as not to spam here, I have a lot of questions

Comment: @SvetoslavPanteleev, no sorry

Comment: Now i saw you fixed it and uploaded in git, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `.mvc.` part, those properties are supposed to be:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```