# Using JSTL, taglibs and custom tags in JSP-alternative projects based on Thymeleaf, Apache Velocity, Apache Freemarker

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf, jsp-tags, taglib

I know two facts:

1) EL (later Unified EL) and taglibs (custom tag libraries, including JSTL) are used within JSP and designed specifically for use within JSP.

2) Alternatives to JSP are: Thymeleaf, Apache Velocity, Apache Freemarker, Facelets (within bigger JSF framework). Plus Struts (it is very old, but still is an "alternative").

My question is: a) is it possible and b) is it good practice to use EL and custom tags / taglibs (including JSTL) within projects using JSP alternatives, or they are JSP-specific and cannot be used outside of JSP?

I think that all those can be used in Facelets/JSF, because before Facelets JSF was JSP-based and I still can mix JSP and Facelets. But what about projects with Thymeleaf, Apache Velocity, Apache Freemarker? And Struts2?

Comment: You can use multiple template Resolvers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480223/using-both-thymeleaf-and-jsp

Answer (score 0):

[Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) supports EL and custom tags / taglibs:

> Using JSP custom tags in FTL
> FreemarkerServlet puts the JspTaglibs hash into the data-model, which you can use to access JSP taglibs. The JSP custom tags will be accessible as plain user-defined directives, and the custom EL functions (since FreeMarker 2.3.22) as methods.

Also [Spring moved from Velocity to FreeMarker](https://nixmash.com/post/the-move-from-velocity-to-freemarker-with-spring-boot) as default template engine

> Velocity Templating support was being phased out in favor of FreeMarker.

Notice also FreeMarker is [no longer in incubation status](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/freemarker.html)  in Apache projects

> The FreeMarker project graduated on 2018-03-21