# Spring thymeleaf doesn't iterate over list

Tags: java, spring, loops, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate over an List and show the results in a table, but the table stays empty.

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public String home(Model model) throws IOException {
        List<OrderNotify> notifications = new ArrayList<OrderNotify>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            OrderNotify notification = new OrderNotify("1", "2", "3", "4");
            notifications.add(notification);
            

        }
            model.addAttribute("notifications", notifications);
            return "home";
    }
```

### home.jsp - table

```
<table id="handle" style=" margin:auto">

    <tr>
        <th>Bestellnummer</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Handlung erforderlich</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="notify : ${notifications}">
        <td th:text="${notify.orderid}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notify.date}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notify.status}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notify.handle}"> </td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

### OrderNotify.java

```
public class OrderNotify {

    public String orderid;
    public String date;
    public String status;
    public String handle;

    public OrderNotify(String orderid, String date, String status, String handle) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
        this.date = date;
        this.status = status;
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public List<String> getAll(){
        return null;
    }

    public String getOrderid() {
        return orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getHandle() {
        return handle;
    }

    public void setHandle(String handle) {
        this.handle = handle;
    }
}
```

I expected do see 10 rows with the same information of the OrderNotify objects of the list, but it was empty. I looked at the source code in the browser and got following result:

```
  <tr th:each="notify : [com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@42b3c931, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@76af8a32, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@28025a03, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@5e6eadf0, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@2481d4d, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@83ce92c, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@3254786a, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@197e42fd, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@5b1e86ea, com.example.spring.utils.OrderNotify@3484712c]">
        <td th:text=""></td>
        <td th:text=""></td>
        <td th:text=""></td>
        <td th:text=""> </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue. First of all browser should not show `th:each="notify : [com.example` etc. view resolver will resolve these things. Do you have thymeleaf spring boot starter dependency in-place? Do you have view-resolver configured in your application?

Comment: Looks like thymeleaf dependency is missing.

Comment: could you update your questions to include your pom.xml as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf and JSP are two different server side rendering templates. You can’t use them simultaneously without configurations.

Basing on your codes, you should update settings for using Thymeleaf:
a.  change home.jsp to home.html 
b.  move home.html to the path: src/main/resources/templates 
c.  config Thymeleaf in application.properties:

```
   # Thymeleaf
   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
   spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
   spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
   spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
   spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

d.  config Thymeleaf dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For Viewing templates, SpringBoot recommends use Thymeleaf instead of JSP, see [more](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) for details.

For using Thymeleaf and JSP simultaneously in SpringBoot app, you need to configure more. Below articles for your reference:

[Using both Thymeleaf and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480223/using-both-thymeleaf-and-jsp)

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Use-Thymeleaf-And-JSP-Simultaneously-In-Spring-Boot-App/